# nginx http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request" with SSL client auth and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, unicorn

I am having a very hard time debugging an issue with nginx(v1.4)_ssl client authentication setup in front of a rails(3.2)/unicorn application running on ubuntu(v14).

DNS and Server setup in AWS route 53 and Ec2.  I have two subdomains

`ca-uat.mydomain.com`

`uat.mydomain.com`

The uat.mydomain.com is non client auth and works fine, I can access rails app.  If I set the nginx

`ssl_verify_client optinal`

I can also access the rails application.  When I turn

`ssl_verify_client on`

I get

nginx http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"

in the error debug log.  It does not give a clear error as to why this is happening.  I am using wget to test and pass the certificate and that seems to be working...

`wget 'https://ca-uat.mydomain.com/client-auth/sso-req' --no-check-certificate --certificate=/etc/ssl/nginx/uat-client.crt --private-key=/etc/ssl/nginx/uat-client.key`

In the debug log I see the client cert being passed and even nginx marking the verified successful header via

`

```
proxy_set_header X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
proxy_set_header X-SSL-ClIENT-S-DN   $ssl_client_s_dn;
proxy_set_header X-CLIENT-VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
```

`

```
2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-CLIENT-VERIFY: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "SUCCESS"
```

Here is the log snippet around the 400 message, any ideas are welcome....
Note I have googled and read this can be b/c of large http header size, however that doesn't seem to be the case here, as I added that config and it didn't help.
`large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;`

log:

```
12014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream request: "/client-auth/sso-req"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream dummy handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D728

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream request: "/client-auth/sso-req"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream process header

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C85480:4096

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 recv: fd:15 28 of 4096

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy header done

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 xslt filter header

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Nginx config:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/home/deploy/mydomain/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name ca-uat.mydomain.com;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/ca-error.log debug;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/ca-access.log ;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/mydomain/mydomain.com.combined.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/mydomain/mydomain.pem;

        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/mydomain/nginx/uat-ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client optional;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;


        location / {
                        proxy_set_header X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
                        proxy_set_header X-SSL-ClIENT-S-DN   $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header X-CLIENT-VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
       }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Full log:

```
    2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: post event 0000000000C5D450

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: delete posted event 0000000000C5D450

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: posix_memalign: 0000000000BF26E0:256 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 accept: 50.17.222.42 fd:14

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer add: 14: 60000:1408484467625

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 epoll add event: fd:14 op:1 ev:80000001

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http check ssl handshake

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http recv(): 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 https ssl handshake: 0x16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000BFBA10:256 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL server name: "ca-uat.caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_do_handshake: -1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_get_error: 2

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL handshake handler: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 verify:1, error:0, depth:1, subject:"/C=US/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxUAT/CN=CareDoxUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com",issuer: "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxUAT/CN=CareDoxUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 verify:1, error:0, depth:0, subject:"/C=NY/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxClientUAT/CN=CareDoxClientUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com",issuer: "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxUAT/CN=CareDoxUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_do_handshake: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http wait request handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C95150:1024

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_read: -1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_get_error: 2

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C95150

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http wait request handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C95150:1024

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_read: 201

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_read: -1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_get_error: 2

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000C91B20:4096 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http process request line

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http request line: "GET /client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com HTTP/1.1"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http uri: "/client-auth/sso-req"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http args: "userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http exten: ""

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http process request header line

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http header: "User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http header: "Accept: */*"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http header: "Host: ca-uat.caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http header: "Connection: Keep-Alive"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http header done

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer del: 14: 1408484467625

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 generic phase: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 rewrite phase: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 test location: "/client-auth/"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 using configuration "/client-auth/"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http cl:-1 max:4294967296

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 rewrite phase: 3

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post rewrite phase: 4

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 generic phase: 5

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 generic phase: 6

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 generic phase: 7

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 access phase: 8

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 access phase: 9

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post access phase: 10

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 try files phase: 11

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000C92B30:4096 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http init upstream, client timer: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 epoll add event: fd:14 op:3 ev:80000005

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000C84470:4096 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-Real-IP: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "50.17.222.42"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "50.17.222.42"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto: https

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-Real-IP: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "50.17.222.42"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-FORWARDED_PROTO: https

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIDijCCAnICAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgYQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYD

....

qhO0gNOKxEpF/vKAO3JQu7mRU6M3eWP8nsZG3H8vIXqKdWNjiXsZQQcpKbK8Og==

-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-SSL-ClIENT-S-DN: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "/C=NY/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxClientUAT/CN=CareDoxClientUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "X-CLIENT-VERIFY: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "SUCCESS"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "Host: "

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script var: "ca-uat.caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: "Connection: close

"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: ""

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http script copy: ""

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy header: "User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy header: "Accept: */*"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy header:

"GET /client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com HTTP/1.0

X-Real-IP: 50.17.222.42

X-Forwarded-For: 50.17.222.42

X-Forwarded-Proto: https

X-Real-IP: 50.17.222.42

X-FORWARDED_PROTO: https

X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIDijCCAnICAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgYQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYD

....
qhO0gNOKxEpF/vKAO3JQu7mRU6M3eWP8nsZG3H8vIXqKdWNjiXsZQQcpKbK8Og==

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

X-SSL-ClIENT-S-DN: /C=NY/ST=NY/L=NYC/O=CareDox/OU=CareDoxClientUAT/CN=CareDoxClientUAT/emailAddress=ben@caredox.com

X-CLIENT-VERIFY: SUCCESS

Host: ca-uat.caredox.com

Connection: close

User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)

Accept: */*



"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http cleanup add: 0000000000C84C60

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 get rr peer, try: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 socket 15

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 epoll add connection: fd:15 ev:80000005

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 connect to unix:/home/deploy/caredox/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock, fd:15 #76

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 connected

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream connect: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000C010B0:128 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream send request

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 chain writer buf fl:1 s:1801

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 chain writer in: 0000000000C93B20

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 writev: 1801

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 chain writer out: 0000000000000000

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer add: 15: 60000:1408484467633

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http finalize request: -4, "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com" a:1, c:2

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http request count:2 blk:0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C70D98

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C5D728

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C70F38

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C70F38

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream request: "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream dummy handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D728

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream request: "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream process header

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C85480:4096

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 recv: fd:15 28 of 4096

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy header done

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 xslt filter header

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 21:40:07 GMT

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Connection: keep-alive



2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000000000C84E98, pos 0000000000C84E98, size: 147 file: 0, size: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:147

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http cacheable: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http proxy filter init s:400 h:0 c:0 l:-1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream process upstream

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe read upstream: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe preread: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 readv: 1:4068

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe recv chain: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 0000000000C85480, pos 0000000000C8549C, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe length: -1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe write downstream: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 pipe write downstream done

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer: 15, old: 1408484467633, new: 1408484467634

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 finalize http upstream request: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 finalize http proxy request

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free rr peer 1 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 close http upstream connection: 15

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C010B0, unused: 48

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer del: 15: 1408484467633

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http upstream temp fd: -1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http output filter "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http copy filter: "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 image filter

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 xslt filter body

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http postpone filter "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com" 00007FFF2CDD4C10

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http chunk: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 write old buf t:1 f:0 0000000000C84E98, pos 0000000000C84E98, size: 147 file: 0, size: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000004A165A, size: 5 file: 0, size: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:152

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http write filter limit 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 posix_memalign: 0000000000C95560:256 @16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C972F0:16384

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL buf copy: 147

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL buf copy: 5

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL to write: 152

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_write: 152

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http write filter 0000000000000000

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http copy filter: 0 "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com"

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http finalize request: 0, "/client-auth/sso-req?userId=1234&parentLastName=Maisano&email=ben%2Bparent@caredox.com" a:1, c:1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 set http keepalive handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http close request

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http log handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C85480

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C91B20, unused: 8

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C92B30, unused: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C84470, unused: 550

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C95150

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 hc free: 0000000000000000 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C972F0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 tcp_nodelay

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer add: 14: 10000:1408484417634

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C70D98

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http empty handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 post event 0000000000C70D98

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C70D98

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http empty handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 delete posted event 0000000000C5D588

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 http keepalive handler

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 malloc: 0000000000C95150:1024

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_read: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_get_error: 5

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 peer shutdown SSL cleanly

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [info] 16978#0: *75 client 50.17.222.42 closed keepalive connection

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 close http connection: 14

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 SSL_shutdown: 1

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 event timer del: 14: 1408484417634

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 reusable connection: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C95150

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000000000

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000BF26E0, unused: 0

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000BFBA10, unused: 16

2014/08/19 21:40:07 [debug] 16978#0: *75 free: 0000000000C95560, unused: 144
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my own issue, wanted to post this so it hopefully helps others.  This was a nasty one b/c it was a compound issue, two separate issues it seems.

1. Passing the full cert upstream to rails seemed to cause the 400 response.  This is inline with something about large http headers, though I couldn't seem to avoid it by increasing.  Not sure if rails app/unicorn needed adjustment.  I ended up not needing that header in app level.  So comment out this in nginx config

   ## proxy_set_header X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
2. This env was hosted on AWS Ec2 behind an elastic load balancer (ELB).  This was the other issue, since it was NOT a TCP ELB but a regular HTTP level ELB it was terminating SSL at the ELB and thereby preventing valid two way SSL (client auth).  I ended up provisioning a separate EC2 instance just for supporting client auth token issuing.  Eventually I'll put a TCP level ELB in front of it with a 2nd instance, but not necessary if this is only job of this server until at large scale.

Comment: I suspect the problem is passing the WHOLE cert, which has to reach unicorn as a single ENV var, IIUC.